# How do I know if I am using infinitely many "steps" in a proof?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, infinity

I am confused about what can and cannot be done in a proof in order to avoid having an infinite number of "steps", thus making the argument invalid.

For instance, let $A_{0}, A_{1}, \dotsc$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose that I want to show that $A_{0}$ satisfies some desired property *after shrinking $A_{1}, A_{2}, \dotsc$*.

Would this be OK? Or would it involve infinitely many "steps"?

In general, how can I make sure my proofs are free from this kind of problems?

EDIT: Using induction, suppose that I can prove that if I shrink $A_{1}, A_{2}, \dotsc$, then $A_{0}$ satisfies the desired property. In other words, I can show that my statement holds when I have just two subsets, and that if it holds for $n$ subsets, then it also holds for $n+1$. But how is this supposed to help me? The hypothesis requires me to shrink an infinite amount of subsets, which looks like too big a task.

Comment: This is too vague.  It depends on the context.

Comment: I think it would depend on what you mean by "shrinking" or why this would constitute "infinitely many steps" versus one step that happens to involve infinity in some way

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but I'd note that any time you are using the $\ldots$ notation you are not being 100% rigorous. That's generally acceptable, but if you are concerned that your reasoning is not valid, I would explicitly use induction and eschew all the dots.

Comment: A proof is a "text" i.e. a sequence of formulas or statement. It must be finite.

Comment: @lulu I agree with you about the vagueness, but that is somehow on purpose. What I am after is some sort of general strategy to detect when an attempted proof has this problem.

Comment: The general strategy is "write out all the steps of your proof".  If you want a vague, but general rule, in order for a "proof by descent" to work, there has to be a discrete counter.  Something that keeps getting lower but which only can only attain finitely many new states.

Comment: "I agree with you about the vagueness, but that is somehow on purpose" The problem is that I don't understand what a single example of the "problem" you would like to avoid looks like. If you could edit to give 2 or 3 different examples of the sort of situation you're worried about (ideally at least one with the problem and at least one where there's no problem) then maybe people could find the common thread and give you a general answer. But with only a vague description, I can think about 5 different kinds of mistakes you *might* be worried about making and don't know which, if any, is right

Comment: For what it's worth, I completely disagree with the close votes: I think this is a nice question that a smart student would ask after reading, say, the flawed argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/37070/156547), while trying to pin down what distinguishes it from normal real analysis proofs where we argue about a sequence of things, like the example given in this question.